# grails Bean Fields plugin still broken?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I tried the [Bean Fields plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/bean-fields) and got the error described here.

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPBEANFIELDS-37

Does anyone know if this has been resolved?  If not, I believe the author definitely needs to update the description of the plugin, to save people time from studying it and attempting to use it.

Comment: I found this in the JIRA:  Guillaume Laforge added a comment - 29/Mar/11 10:49 AM

Users will probably have to wait for a Grails release including Groovy 1.7.10 which fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm going to stick with my first comment: the author definitely needs to update the description of the plugin, to save people time from studying it and attempting to use it.

Comment: Thanks for comment Don.  I wonder why he didn't include it, as apparently time is / has been taken under the plugin to track all the issues in the issues section, i.e. http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPBEANFIELDS#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aissues-panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bean-Fields plugin is not broken - Groovy shipped with Grails 1.3.7 contains a bug. There is no workaround that I am aware of, and the problem only affects bean:field.

I was unable to get clarification of the root cause of the bug so was unable to craft a workaround. I spent a lot of time on this already.

Bean-Fields works well enough - just don't use bean:field in Grails 1.3.7, that's what we had to do in our projects.

The new field rendering mechanisms for Grails 2 are in progress, using new code taking the best ideas of Bean Fields and taking it to the next level. No ETA yet, but this is being worked on by members of the GPC.

Comment: Marc, thanks for your response -- good to hear Grails 2 is adopting your ideas.

Comment: Marc, I'm looking out for this functionality in the tag docs of Grails 2, and have not encountered any as of yet.  Do you know any tags I need to look out for?